# Getting an Infinite Loop in for statement in python. What is wrong in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python and was trying some code stuff and erroneously found this. I am not able to understand the behaviour of code? what is causing infinite loop ?

> ```
> any_list=[""]
>  
> for x in any_list:
>
>    any_list.append("something")
> ```

Comment: `any_list` has one element. The `for` loop iterate 1 time for this element, `""`, and then you modify the list that is being iterated on, inside the iteration.

Comment: try printing out any_list inside the loop and see what happens.

Comment: As a general rule, never modify a structure that you are iterating over.

Comment: You are extending the list on every iteration, so it will be endless.

Comment: okay. yeah basic stuffs. got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are looping and adding an item to the `any_list` at the same time. So it goes on forever.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new item to the list each iteration, thus causing the length of `any_list` to increase, which extends the loop.